# How to force update of ng-init ?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I found that ng-init is not updated after rowIndex is updated.

```
<div ng-init="item = getItem(rowIndex)">
   {{ item.Name }} 
</div>
```

item is not updated after rowIndex is changed (even if changes are made with $timeout)

Is there other directive that allows to avoid using the following dirty trick:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in [getItem(rowIndex)]">
   {{ item.Name }} 
</div>
```

Comment: `ng-repeat` has a watcher (over a collection), so just get a watcher any other way. That depends on how `rowIndex` is updated. If somewhere within an input filed, use `ng-changed="updateItem(rowIndex,item)"`. If somewhere else, then use `$scope.$watch('item', function() {$scope.item = getItem(rowIndex); ...`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another approach is to set the variable inside a bogus attribute:

```
<div x="{{item = getItem(rowIndex)}}">
    {{ item.Name }} {{item.Value}}
</div>
```

On each digest cycle the value of `item` will be updated.

In this case where `item` has more that one property, the `getItem` function needs to be invoked only once.

Keep in mind that it would be even more efficient for the controller to update the value of `item` only once when `rowIndex` changes instead of invoking the `getItem` function every digest cycle.

---

## Avoid using `ng-init`

Avoid using `ng-init`. It tangles the Model and View, making code difficult to understand, test, debug, and maintain. Instead initialize the Model in the controller.

From the Docs:

> ## ngInit
>
> > This directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of `ngInit`, such as for aliasing special properties of `ngRepeat`, as seen in the demo below; and for injecting data via server side scripting. Besides these few cases, you should use [controllers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) rather than `ngInit` to initialize values on a scope.
>
> [— AngularJS ng-init Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

Comment: Neat! Is there any benefit to using this over calling the `getItem` method inside the curly braces?

Comment: In this case where `item` has more that one property, the `getItem` function needs to be invoked only once.

Answer (score 4):

`ngInit` does not update. It's a one-shot directive. You should just call the function from within the curly braces, since you are wanting to watch for changes to `rowIndex`:

```
<div>
  {{ getItem(rowIndex).Name }}
</div>
```

This could hurt performance on large lists, since `getItem` will be called on every digest cycle, but it's easy to read.

https://plnkr.co/edit/cZ2SG6nf2SufdAWe1ye7?p=preview